# closing a XLSX workbook handler created using in perl?

Tags: perl

I have opened a xlsx file using `$workbook = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new($filename)`,
and close the above handler if the contents fails for some conditions `$wrokbook-> close()`,

But it gives the error:

> Can't locate object method "close" via package "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook".

Is there any other method to close the handler ?

Comment: Well, it depends on the confition which you are not giving us but typically something like `if (!defined $myexcel) {
    die "Error: " . $myexcel->error() . "\n";
}`

Comment: failing the condition means user defined conditions such as  it doesn't have the specified  columns. Then I want to close the file and exit the script

Comment: well, then there you have it. you make it die

Comment: I want to close the file handler before I exit the script. i.e closing the spreadsheet prior to exit

Comment: It's impossible not to.

Comment: Also, they are called "file handles" (they hold a resource), not "file handlers" (they don't handle anything).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to close any handles. Perl will do that for you automatically when it exits.

In addition, most modules use lexical file handles (or database handles or whatever), so they get cleaned up automatically when the variable that holds the object goes out of scope.

Therefore, **don't do anything**. If your program fails, just `exit` with an error code, or `die`. All the resources will be freed by Perl for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Spreadhseet::XLSX module once. With this module you can only read the contents of the file and not write anything to the excel. 
This module does not creates any special file handles.

When you try to create a new excel object, this module just parses the entire excel file and saves all the data from excel to the object. So, you don't have to explicitly close anything.

Now to handle any exceptions(like invalid path, invalid file name) during the creation of excel object, you can do something like this,

```
eval{
    my $excelObject = Spreadsheet::XLSX->new($filename);
};
die "Unable to read the excel file. Error: ".$@ if($@);
```